# Jmeter workload modelling

Tags: jmeter, workload

I have 5 scenarios for my web application. The ratio in which to hit these scenarios are as follows : 10:25:30:5:30. I want to run the test for 5 hours. In the first hour the number of users should be 100, in the next hour it should be 80, then it should be 200, in the 4th hour it should be 500 and in the last hour it should be 300. How to achieve this workload modelling in Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to configure your model is using 5 different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group), maybe even [Ultimate Thread Groups](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) as it is much easier to control users arrival rate with it, to simulate the desired distribution.

If for some reason you need to keep all the requests for different scenarios in a single Thread Group, you have the following choices:

1. [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
2. [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
3. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/)

P.S:

- Ultimate Thread Group and Weighted Switch Controller are available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project
- See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for different approaches of running "weighted" tasks explained

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri.. :-)